# android: Running a time consuming task in UI Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, eclipse, background-process

in my app i am trying to process a task in the UI Thread when a button is clicked (the task is executed only once when the button is clicked)... since the task is time consuming my UI gets frozen and doesn't allow the user for further input...

my question is that is there any other method apart from "Thread"s to run my task so that my UI doesn't get frozen ..since i don't want the task to run repeatedly..

if possible can u provide me with sample code or links....

thanks :)

Comment: Any solution is going to involve doing work on a separate thread.  However, as EboMike pointed out, there are easier ways of doing than creating a new Runnable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AsyncTask is a very convenient way for that, it has great hooks for initialization and clean-up.

Docs including example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).